How to deal with paired tumor-normal samples in Snakemake?
I am converting a bash pipeline to process paired whole-exome sequenced tumor-normal samples into a SnakeMake workflow.
Paired samples are listed in my config file, as follows:
sample_list:
  - sample: 1
    tumor: AO1_04_RN_1_T_4_S4
    control: AO2_07_C007558T1Wa_S37
  - sample: 2
    tumor: AO2_01_C007589T1FTa_S2
    control: AO2_07_C007589T1Wa_S34
  - sample: 3
    tumor: AO9_09_FM_1_T_7_S13 
    control: AO2_07_C007558T1Wa_S37

I am now stuck in getting a rule to call variants with Mutect2 to process the tumor samples from sample X specifically with its control sample (e.g. for sample 1: -I tumor_of_sample_1 -I control_of_sample_1).
What I keep getting (even using zip) is a command built like this: -I tumor_of_sample_1 tumor_of_sample_2 tumor_of_sample_3 -I control_of_sample_1 control_of_sample_2 control_of_sample_3, which inevitably fails.
I would be very grateful for some help...thanks!

I think what you need is a simple lambda function to grab the correct config entry for a given wildcard.I changed your config file a bit, which makes the lambda function a bit simpler, otherwise it should be trivial to adjust the function accordingly (I think, have not tested it)
sample_list:
    sample1:
      tumor: sample1_tumor.gz
      control: sample1_control.gz
    sample2:
      tumor: sample2_tumor.gz
      control: sample2_control.gz
    sample3:
      tumor: sample2_tumor.gz
      control: sample2_control.gz

And the conresponding snakefile:
configfile: "config.yml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("out/{ID}.procesed",ID=["sample1","sample2","sample3"])

rule test:
    input:
        tumor=lambda wc: "input/"+config["sample_list"][wc.ID]["tumor"],
        control=lambda wc: "input/"+config["sample_list"][wc.ID]["control"]
    output:
        "out/{ID}.procesed"
    shell:
        "echo {input.tumor} {input.control} {output}"


Great answer. If you want to keep the original config file format, conversion can be done in one line at the top of the Snakefile: sample_list = { i["sample"]: i for i in config["sample_list"] }. I'd do that rather then complicating the lambda expressions in the rule.

Thanks very much @TimBooth, great help!
Combining your suggestions to keep the original config file (as per my original question at the top) I got it working as I meant.
Would there be a way to name the output file using the tumor string from my config file above, instead of the sample ID?
I thought I could define ID outside of rule all too, somehow...but it seems I can't - and that blocks me from changing the output file name while keeping this working.
Thank you
